# Shorten JS if or statement

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to shorten something like this in Javascript: `if (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4)` to something like if `(x == (1 || 2 || 3 || 4))` ?

Comment: If you're looking for syntax similar to what you posted, then no. You should consider that any roundabout way of shortening it will suffer a performance hit.

Comment: Numbers were used as an example so using "if(x >0 && x < 5)" would not be useful if I am comparing strings.

Answer (score 7):

You can use use [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
[1,2,3,4].indexOf(x) !== -1
```

You can also use objects as some kind of hash map:

```
//Note: Keys will be coerced to strings so
// don't use this method if you are looking for an object or if you need
// to distinguish the number 1 from the string "1"
my_values = {1:true, 2:true, 3:true, 'foo':true}
my_values.hasOwnProperty('foo')
```

---

By the way, in most cases you should usi the "===" strict equality operator instead of the `==` operator. Comparison using "==" may do lots of complicated type coercion and you can get surprising results sometimes.

Comment: Well *sometimes* "==" is useful, but you're probably right that "===" should be what a JavaScript programmer types automatically :-)

Comment: speaking about coercion, object initializer does it thrice :-P

Answer (score 2):

If your cases are not that simple to be expressed by this:

```
if (1 <= x && x <= 4)
```

You could use an [array and `indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if ([1,2,3,4].indexOf(x) > -1)
```

Note that `indexOf` might need to be re-implemented.

Comment: After removal of spaces, it's actually 1 character longer *(referring to `indexOf()`)*, but given a longer list of matches, it would be shorter. I guess it depends on actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Not without writing a function that takes an array as an input and returns true/false, or some sort of array search.  It would be hard to maintain/other devs to read.  And it would be significantly slower.  So just stick with the semantically correct longer version.

Also a good way to see if anything can be shortened significantly is to run it through the close compiler and see what it comes out with.

Comment: I second this. It's often a good idea to encapsulate complex checks like this into a func to communicate the meaning better.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if (x > 0 && x < 5) {
}
```

Comment: I thought this, but then I realised John was presenting it as a simplified example not a case study so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function:

```
function isAny(x) {
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; ++i)
    if (arguments[i] === x) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Then you can say:

```
if (isAny(x, 1, 2, 3, 4)) { /* ... */ }
```

(Whether to use "===" or "==" would depend on the exact semantics you want.)